# Всплывающее окно. Частичное копирование буфера окна консоли - C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Пишу курсовой в VS2017 на С++, нужно реализовать что то вроде ***всплывающего окна*** :

- на экране консоли выведены данные, нужно вырезать часть экрана, в
  этом месте вывести окно из псевдографики, после вместо окна обратно
  вернуть то что было.

В результате поисков понял что это возможно реализовать с помощью **winapi функций управляющих screen buffer**, но более глубокой литературы найти не удалось. (Пользоваться дополнительными библиотеками запрещено)

Буду благодарен за наводки на полезные источники по данной теме, или за помощь с кодом. Спасибо ￼

Comment: https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-ncurses-hello-world/   и  https://code-live.ru/post/ncurses-input-output/

Comment: Я нечто подобное реализовывал полной перерисовкой окна

Comment: Дополнительные библиотеки подключать запретили(

Comment: Через перерисовку тоже сделал, но хотелось бы разобраться с тем, что хуже понимаю, да и оно будет лучше работать в теории)

Comment: Вы если что-то делаете, то дополняйте текст вопроса, либо оформите отдельным ответом.